# How do I make detail of an exception thrown by IOperationInvoker visible to silverlight?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a set of RIA domain services that use an overriden OnError operation to throw DomainExceptions.  This works perfectly and allows the silverlight client to identify the base exception types via the embedded error code.  However my RIA service operations are attributed to include a number of implementaions of IOperationInvoker to inject pre-invoke and post-invoke behaviour.

If an exception is thrown by any of the code in these IOperationInvoker operations the silverlight client gets a DomainOperationException containing a FaultException.  Even though the thrown exception is a FaultException the received fault appears be be devoid of any the original detail only containing the textual message.

I have tried catching the exception in the IOperationInvoker and converting it to a DomainException but this does not change what is visible in Silverlight.

Is there any way I can throw an Exception from the IOperationInvoker so that it is surfaced in the Silverlight client as a DomainException i.e. including the error code as if it had come from the DomainService operation that is wrapped by the IOperationInvoker?